# If decimal is null

Tags: apex, decimal

I have a query that sometimes returns a value if the current user has a record. If they do not no value is loaded and my vf page does not show a gauge.

Today, I have been tweaking the controller to divide the value by 100,000 so the gauge is easier to read. When I look at the gauge on a page it gives an error that it is trying to de-reference a null object.

I think this is because I'm dividing by a null value. So I want to put in a if to only do the division if there is a value.

Does this seem like the right approach?

Here is my controller class:

```
public with sharing class ISOGaugeControllerIndividualCurMo {
public Integer getMax2() {
    Decimal max1 = 1;
    Integer max2 = 0;
    AggregateResult max =   [select sum(Goal__c) goal 
                            FROM ISO_Goal__c 
                            Where Goal__c != null 
                            AND (Goal_Date__c = THIS_MONTH OR Goal_Date__c = LAST_MONTH)
                            AND RecordType.Name = 'Individual Goal'
                            AND OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

    max1 = (Decimal)max.get('goal');
    if (max1 == 1) {
    max2 = (Integer)max1.divide(100000, 0);
        }
    return max2;
    }
public List<gaugeData> getData() {

    AggregateResult Actuals =   [select sum(amount__c) sum 
                                FROM Actuals__c 
                                Where Amount__c != null 
                                AND (Actual_Date__c = THIS_MONTH OR Actual_Date__c = LAST_MONTH)
                                AND ISO_Goal__r.RecordType.Name = 'Individual Goal'
                                AND ISO_Goal__r.OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

    List<gaugeData> data = new List<gaugeData>();
    data.add(new gaugeData('Actual', (Integer)((Decimal)actuals.get('sum')).divide(100000, 0)));
    return data;
}
// Wrapper class
public class gaugeData {

public String name { get; set; }
public Integer size { get; set; }

public gaugeData(String name, Integer data) {
    this.name = name;
    this.size = data;
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: Instead of using if (max1 == 1) why not just use if max1 != null ?

Comment: Hey Dan, did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes, I used Sebastian's example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do something like this. It's cleaner and achieves your stated goal

```
max2 = (max1 == null) ? 0 : (Integer)max1.divide(100000, 0);
```

Also, I would either remove the `if` statement above or incorporate it into the ternary, like the below

```
max2 = (max1 == null || max != 1) ? 0 : (Integer)max1.divide(100000, 0);
```

Comment: Um. You want to send all values except `1` to `0`? That doesn't sound right...

Comment: I'm just mimicking the `if` statement the OP had around the division originally. Hence my two samples, he might have a good reason for doing it.

Comment: I don't was just trying to get some value in there so the page renders.

Comment: then the first sample is what you need

Comment: Still get dereference error

   'public Integer getMax2() {
        AggregateResult max =   [select sum(Goal__c) goal 
                                FROM ISO_Goal__c ...
        Decimal max1 = (Decimal)max.get('goal');
        Integer max2 = (max1 == null) ? 0 : (Integer)max1.divide(100000, 0);
        return max2;
        }'

Comment: that's not your problem, then. what line is failing?

Comment: Looking at the debug log it stops after the query. I'm able to save the class so it's not a compile error that I can see into a specific line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40020/discussion-between-dan-wooding-and-sebastian-kessel).

Answer (score 5):

I commonly create a method called `elide` for this issue:

```
public Decimal elide(Decimal input) { return (input == null) ? 0 : input; }
```

With it, you can simply do:

```
max2 = (Integer)elide(max1).divide(100000, 0);
```

Comment: `elide` - I have not seen this word before in the context of computer science, only in speech. My similar function, clunkier-named is `makeOperandable()`

Comment: @cropredy tbh, don't remember where I picked that term up from and I'm not entirely sure if it's correct. I've used it for a couple years now, though.